# Lambda "if" statement?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have 2 objects, both of which I want to convert to dictionarys. I use toDictionary<>().

The lambda expression for one object to get the key is (i => i.name). For the other, it's (i => i.inner.name). In the second one, i.name doesn't exist. i.inner.name ALWAYS exists if i.name doesn't.

Is there a lambda expression I can use to combine these two? Basically to read as:

"if i.name exists then set id to i.name, else set id to i.inner.name".

Many thanks.

**Update**

When I say "don't exist", I mean the objects don't actually have the properties, not that the properties are just null.

Comment: If you say that the properties don't exist, do you mean that the objects actually don't have the properties, or that the properties are just null?

Comment: The objects don't actually have the properties.

Comment: So then these two types are two completely unrelated types then?

Comment: @shf301 yes. However, all of them either have a name property, or a object.name property of type string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you give each object a `ToDictionary` method of their own, as they obviously have their own behaviours in this case.

If you can't add to the objects, because you don't own them, you can always write extension methods for them.

Any reason your trying to force feed them into one "common" function?

Comment: Maybe overriding ToString() would be the best behavioural choice for these objects.  Of course, that depends on whether you rely on other behaviour in ToString() elsewhere...

Comment: @Sekhat I was just seeing if I could combine it into one function as I need to do it quite a few times. For the sake of tidiness.

Answer (score 14):

If these are two distinct (reference) types then you can test them using the [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) or [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) keywords:

```
i => {
         var x = i as TypeThatHasNameProperty;
         return (x != null) ? x.name : i.inner.name;
     }
```

If you can't test for specific types then you can use reflection to test for the `name` property itself:

```
i => {
         var pi = i.GetType().GetProperty("name");
         return (pi != null) ? pi.GetValue(i, null) : i.inner.name;
     }
```

Comment: Don't you need to cast `i` to `TypeThatHasNameProperty` before you can access the `Name` property?

Comment: @dtb: Probably, I suppose it depends on what the rest of the OP's code looks like. (But it wouldn't do any harm to make the cast anyway, although in my example code I think using `as` is probably more appropriate than a plain cast.)

Comment: great job on this answer

Comment: This is a more appropriate answer

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the conditional operator ("ternary operator") does what you want:

```
(i => i.name != null ? i.name : i.inner.name)
```

Assuming, of course, that you can detect the "existence" of the name by checking for `null`.

**Edit**: In that case, Kirschstein's answer is better, of course.

Comment: What I meant is, i.name doesn't exist at all. The property name isn't there. I can't use null.

Apologies if I made that unclear.

Answer (score 0):

something along the lines of

```
collection1.ForEach(i => myDictionary.Add((i.name.length == 0 ? i.inner.name : i.name),value);
```

(untested) should do the trick if i.name is not null (an empty string), or

```
collection1.ForEach(i => myDictionary.Add((i.name ?? i.inner.name),value);
```

(also untested)

Answer (score -1):

as an inline if query I would use a ternary operator, so:

```
(i.name != null ? set id to i.name : set id to i.inner.name)
```