# Lambda instead of "if" statement

Tags: python, lambda, if-statement, lambda-calculus

I've heard that it is possible to substitute an `if` statement by using a lambda.

Is this possible in Python? If so, how?

Comment: It would help if you provided a reference or gave an example in another language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the others, I'm not sure what you're asking about, but I'm willing to have a guess.

I sometimes use lambdas in a bit of a hacky way processing results from API calls.

Say for example an element of an API call result should be a numeric string which I'd want as an integer, but occasionally it returns something else.

You could defined a lambda to turn a string into an integer if it is comprised of digits:

```
lambda x: x and x.isdigit() and int(x) or None
```

This is avoiding an `if` statement, but not because of the `lambda`, you could do the same as a function:

```
def f(x):
  return x and x.isdigit() and int(x) or None
```

---

**Update**

Less buggy hack, courtesy of Paul McGuire:

```
lambda x: int(x) if x and x.isdigit() else None
```

*i.e. as `int('0')` returns an equivalent of `False` the lambda might surprise you by returning `None` when you wanted `0`*

Comment: This is just the old workaround for having no ternary operator in Python wrapped in a lambda, modern way would be `int(x) if x and x.isdigit() else None`, though that means you don't want to convert '0.0'.

Comment: As @agf points out, this old workaround has always carried the risk of doing the wrong thing if one of the terms evaluates successfully to a value that Python treats as a boolean False. If you are going to instruct someone on this hack, at least use a less buggy hack: `lambda x : int(x) if x and x.isdigit() else None`.  Now you won't get surprised when x is '0'.

Comment: What if x is "-1"? x.isdigit() returns False here too.

Comment: @Paul, then this wouldn't be a useful function. It was just an example of a guess at what the OP was looking for. Where I use it, the input is a text representation of a positive integer or I don't want it

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you are referring to something like this ([Lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Logic_and_predicates))?

```
If = lambda test, x, y: test(x, y)
True = lambda x, y: x
False = lambda x, y: y
```

Which you could use like...

```
# I guess you have to convert them sometimes... oh well
C = lambda b: [False, True][b]

x = If(C(2 > 3), "Greater", "Less")
print(x)
# "Less"
```

But now things start to fall apart...

```
If(C(2 > 3), print("Greater"), print("Less"))
# Invalid syntax unless you use
    #     from __future__ import print_function
# And if you do, it prints both!
# (Because python has eager evaluation)

# So we could do
True = lambda x, y: x()
False = lambda x, y: y()

# And then
If(C(2 > 3), lambda:print("Greater"), lambda:print("Less"))
# "Less"
```

So, not so pretty, or useful. But it works.

Comment: Um, it is if you put commas between the arguments to the lambda expressions? And maybe show an example of how it would be used? (For my benefit, if noone else's)

Answer (score 3):

I might be seriously off, but I'd imagine this means something like:

```
filter(lambda x: x > 0, list_of_values)
```

Would return you the elements from `list_of_values` which have a value greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

Following is a little trick inspired by Smalltalk
language core, which does not use if statement nor ternary
operator, yet working as a conditional execution
mechanism. :-)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
class ATrue:
  def ifThen(self,iftrue): iftrue()
  def ifThenElse(self,iftrue,iffalse): return iftrue()
  def andThen(self,other): return other()
  def orElse(self,other): return self

class AFalse:
  def ifThen(self,iftrue): pass
  def ifThenElse(self,iftrue,iffalse): return iffalse()
  def andThen(self,other): return self
  def orElse(self,other): return other()

def echo(x): print x

if __name__=='__main__':
  T = ATrue()
  F = AFalse()

  x = T                    # True
  y = T.andThen(lambda: F) # True and False
  z = T.orElse(lambda: F)  # True or False

  x.ifThenElse( lambda: echo("x is True"), lambda: echo("x if False"))
  y.ifThenElse( lambda: echo("y is True"), lambda: echo("y if False"))
  z.ifThenElse( lambda: echo("z is True"), lambda: echo("z if False"))
```

UPDATE: Tidy up some symbols to avoid confusion and make the point clear. And added code to show how short-cut evaluation of logical operators can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

```
if condition:
    do_stuff()
else:
    dont()
```

is

```
(lambda x: do_stuff() if x else dont())(condition)
```

But it's not clear what you're looking for.

Note that this is **not** an `if` statement -- it's a [ternary operation](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Ternary_operation). In Python, they just both use the word `if`. See for example [Lambda "if" statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476619/lambda-if-statement) for this in C#.

Comment: well, you're actually using the if statement :)

Comment: It's not an `if` statement, it's a ternary operator. When I googled this topic, that's what the results used (in C#, for example). Python's ternary operator just happens to use the word `if`.